# Generate HTML form from JS model (with bindings)

Tags: javascript, binding, auto-generate

I am interested in a JS library that does the following.
Given a model, for example

```
{
    name: 'James Smith',
    level : 3,
    groups: ['admins', 'users']
}
```

it should create a set of fields and bindings, for example:

```
<input type='text' name='name' data-bind='value: name' />
<input type='number' name='name' data-bind='value: level' />
<div data-bind="foreach: group">
   <!-- ... group binding, also add/remove buttons ... --> 
</div>
```

(Using Knockout syntax, but any other binding library would do as well).
I know this is ambiguous for a complex model, but some ability to extend the rules easily resolves it, so it is far from impossible.

I do understand how to build that if I have to, but I would prefer to use existing library.

Comment: Is this some kind of form generator you want to create?

Comment: You could say so, though I do not want to create a form generator framework, I want to find one.